# Excel - How to combine multiple files using power query M and keeping files names

Tags: excel, powerquery

When I combine files using power query with **Office Standard 2016** I get a unique sheet with all my files contents and also **the name of each files as a new column**.

When I try to do the same with **Office Pro plus 2016**, I get a unique sheet with all my files contents but **without the name of each files**.

If I made the query on **Office Standard 2016** and move it to **Office Pro plus 2016** it just don't working anymore and I get an error :

> Expression.Error: the Csv.Document "Columns" parameter is not available

So, Both versions made the same operation in two different ways and for a different result, that's very annoying.

Is anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a sample of your code, but a generic version to combine CSV files and retain source data info is:

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "CSV", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content]))),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[CSV], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "CSV", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: I have to remove Table.PromoteHeaders() (my files don't have any headers) but it's working well this way thanks @horseyride